# How to pass cognito confidential app client credentials for creating boto3 cognito-idp client?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

Context

- Created aws cognito userpool
- Created 2 app clients for that user pool first **public client** (for frontend), second **confidential client** (for backend)
- Created frontend in react that uses aws cognito, frontend passes idToken to server
- Server is able to verify idToken and able to extract username from that id token.

Problem

I'm trying to update user attributes from backend, using `CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_update_user_attributes` But getting an error `The security token included in the request is invalid.`.

For aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key I'm passing the values that I got while creating aws cognito confidential app client. IE app client id and app client secret key.

Code

```py
import boto3

user_pool_id = "xxx"

client = boto3.client(
  'cognito-idp', 
  aws_access_key_id="xxx", 
  aws_secret_access_key="xxx", 
  region_name='xxx'
)

print(client.admin_get_user(
  UserPoolId="xxx", 
  Username="xxx"
))
```

Exception thrown

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListUsers operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Answer (score 1):

What I was doing was completely wrong.

The documentation read `Calling this action requires developer credentials`.
Which means you cannot use app client id and app client secret for granting access to cognito-idp:Admin* actions. You need to create IAM user with proper permissions.

The solution was to

1. create IAM policy with `cognito-idp:*` permissions
2. create new IAM user and attach the policy just created.
3. use access_key_id and access_key_secret for that user to initialize boto client.